# Flutter Image Picker

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

Getting this weird error. When I add image_picker: ^0.8.5+3 to my project, it gives me the following runtime error. [image]

The same package I'm using in my other project and works perfectly. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Flutter Doctor:
[image]

Comment: Delete pubspec.lock file then do flutter clean, flutter pub get and run the application.

Comment: Thanks, brother. Did everything but delete pubspec.lock. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In ios folder open Podfile. The platform version will be 9 and commented. Uncomment this line and make the platform version 11.0 and try again

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```